# Nginx as reverse proxy on Raspberry Pi with Docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, nginx

On my Raspberry Pi, I've an ASP. NET Core sample web application running within a Docker container. It has been started with the following command:

```
docker run --name aspnetcore_sample --rm -d -p 8000:80 mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/samples:aspnetapp
```

Within a SSH session, I can successfully execute `curl localhost:8000`.

Now I'd like to use Nginx as a reverse proxy, so that I can call `http://myraspi/demo` from any browser within the network. For this, I've installed Nginx and `http://myraspi` is working (Nginx welcome site is returned).

Afterwards, I've created the file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myraspi.conf` with the following content:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myraspi;

    location /demo {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
    }
}
```

Followed by the command `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myraspi.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myraspi.conf`. 
The check with `sudo nginx - t` succeeds and a final restart with `sudo nginx -s reload`.

However, when executing `curl localhost/demo` within the SSH session or `http://myraspi/demo` from any outside browser, Nginx gives me `404 Not Found`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that it’s nginx that gives you the 404 and not your ASP.NET Core application? Can you try to confirm that through the logs? The reason I am asking is because you are using nginx to host the application at a subpath `/demo`. Out of the box this won’t work because the ASP.NET Core application doesn’t know about that path and will see it as a normal request path. You will have to configure the *path base* first. Check out [my answer here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45312462/216074).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So there is no way solve that issue by configuration? Because if I understand your answer correctly, I'd have to modify the code of the ASP.NET Core sample app. Do you know any other way (maybe another web server)?

Comment: There is not really another way if you want to host the app at a subpath. What you could do is pass a custom HTTP header to the application and interpret that to set the path base dynamically within your ASP.NET Core application. That way, the reverse proxy can configure it from the outside without you having to recompile your application.