# .NET Core RedirectToAction not working correctly behind Nginx

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx-reverse-proxy, http-redirect

I'm trying to deploy my web api behind nginx.

My web API is always start with `http://<host>/api/<controllerName>`
But I use Nginx reverse proxy to handling test and prod server request

The request to test server `http://<host>/api/<controllerName>/<action>` turn to `http://<host>/test/api/<controllerName>/<action>`

Everything is OK so far except I use `RedirectToActionResult` in some action. It still redirect to url to `http://<host>/api/<controllerName>/<action>` format. Is there any way I could adjust `RedirectToActionResult` to redirect with prefix like `http://<host>/test/api/<controllerName>/<action>`?

Or I have to modify the whole API server url with prefix path.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `ASPNETCORE_PATHBASE=/test` in your Environment.

And in your `Startup.cs`, you can add below code.

```
var pathBase = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_PATHBASE");
app.UsePathBase(new PathString(pathBase))
```

*Related Post:*

[ASP.Net Core Reverse Proxy with different root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45311393/asp-net-core-reverse-proxy-with-different-root)