How to handle urls correctly with a reverse proxy (.net core views/home/* location 404 error)
I am currently using PHP web service on this domain.
(ex) www.mydomain.com
I am also making an English site and making it .net core web service,
but I am planning to replace it with .net core instead of using PHP.
By adding /eng to the existing domain,
I was able to successfully connect to the .net web service.
(ex) www.mydomain.com/eng
(apache httpd.conf)
ProxyPass /eng http://localhost:5296/
ProxyPassReverse /eng http://localhost:5296/

Since css and js were not applied, I modified the code below and succeeded.
(Program.cs)
app.Use((httpContext, next) =>
     {
         httpContext.Request.PathBase = "/eng";
         return next();
     });

However, when I try to access the Views/Home/ subpage (ex. Privacy.cshtml) in .net core mvc, a 404 error appears.
(Controllers > HomeController.cs)
[Route("Privacy")]
public IActionResult Privacy() {
         return View();
}

I wanted to add reverse proxy settings,
so I added the code below,
but I still got a 404 error.
ProxyPass /eng/Home/ http://localhost:5296/Home/
ProxyPassReverse /eng/Home/ http://localhost:5296/Home/

ProxyPass /eng/Views/Home/ http://localhost:5296/Views/Home/
ProxyPassReverse /eng/Views/Home/ http://localhost:5296/Views/Home/

The files in the wwwroot subfolder are connected,
but why are the Views/Home subfolders not?

I found a solution. When I applied the comment in the link below, it was resolved for me too.
I got this working finally. Turns out UsePathBase works correctly, my Nginx proxy was just configured wrong (as you pointed out). Trailing slashes on Nginx locations and proxy_pass will not work. It should look like: location /app { proxy_pass http://app:5000; }, and NOT location /app/ { proxy_pass http://app:5000/; }
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45311393/asp-net-core-reverse-proxy-with-different-root?rq=2

I found a solution. When I applied the comment in the link(ASP.Net Core Reverse Proxy with different root)
, it was resolved for me too.
I got this working finally. Turns out UsePathBase works correctly, my Nginx proxy was just configured wrong (as you pointed out). Trailing slashes on Nginx locations and proxy_pass will not work.
It should look like:
location /app { proxy_pass http://app:5000; }

, and NOT
location /app/ { proxy_pass http://app:5000/; }

